# LINQ to Entities - parse / filter object collection

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I am trying to filter a list of users from my database.

When I run this LINQ to Entity  command, it works as I had hoped.  It returns all users, filtered by whatever is in `txtFilterBy_UserName` :

(notice that I am accessing the db table directly.  There are also several fields to filter on, but I only include username in this example)

```
users = db.Users
          .Where(u => u.IsActive == true &&
                      u.UserName.ToLower()
                       .Contains((txtFilterBy_UserName.Value.Length > 0) ? 
                                  u.UserName.ToLower() : 
                                  txtFilterBy_UserName.Value.ToLower()))
          .ToList();
```

But... in some circumstances I have already populated my User collection (`_users`) before filtering, and I expected to be able to do this:

```
users = _users.Where(u => u.IsActive == true && 
                          u.UserName.ToLower()
                           .Contains((txtFilterBy_UserName.Value.Length > 0) ?
                                      u.UserName.ToLower() :
                                      txtFilterBy_UserName.Value.ToLower()))
              .ToList();
```

But this method always returns 0 users, can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong, or why this method of filtering the user collection doesn't work ?

Let's say my DB has 100 users in it and 6 of those users have the characters "john" in their username. When I query the DB directly - I return 6 users.
If the users collection object is already populated (with 100 users) and I try filtering the collection - 0 users are returned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using ternary operator for filtering, simply compose your query by conditionally adding `Where` filters:

```
var query = _users.Where(u => u.IsActive); // don't compare boolean with true
if (txtFilterBy_UserName.Value.Length > 0)
    query = query.Where(u => u.UserName.ToLower().Contains(txtFilterBy_UserName.Value.ToLower()));

var users = query.ToList();
```

And yes, I agree with @Abbas - your query looks fines. Probably you don't have any user matching your condition in local `_users` collection.

Comment: Thanks very much for this solution - I was so desperate to try and get it working with such minimal code, but this makes more sense and it works !

Answer (score 1):

Does the collection `_users` contain any users at all (before filtering)? Also, your query looks weird to me, please correct me if I'm wrong:

```
u.UserName.ToLower().Contains((txtFilterBy_UserName.Value.Length > 0)
                              ? u.UserName.ToLower()
                              : txtFilterBy_UserName.Value.ToLower())
```

I read this as:

If the filter-textbox has a value (Length > 0) give me all the users where the lowercase username of any user contains the lowercase username of that user, otherwise (if no filter-value is provided) give me all the users where the lowercase username contains an empty value (string).

Comment: +1 for pointing on weird query. Btw _users not necessary empty - it could not have users matching condition

Comment: I think we are going a bit off-topic, but I'd like to explain what this line should do. (txtFilterBy_UserName (and the other filters) have a Watermark in them) If the filter text box contains a value (and the value is not "username") then return me users in the db that match the value in txtFilterBy_UserName, otherwise return me all users whether they have a username or not...
Here's my full condition.

u.UserName.ToLower().Contains(((txtFilterBy_UserName.Value.Length > 0) && (txtFilterBy_UserName.Value.ToLower() == "username")) ? u.UserName.ToLower() : txtFilterBy_UserName.Value.ToLower())

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you got your query a bit mixed up. Looking at your code I suspect you want to do this:

1. If `txtFilterBy_UserName.Value.Length > 0` is **true** then you only want to return users which username contains `txtFilterBy_UserName.Value`. Essentially you will be doing filtering.
2. If `txtFilterBy_UserName.Value.Length > 0` is **false** then you want to return all users. Here you don't apply any filter.

If my assumption is correct, you could rewrite your query as follows:

```
users = db.Users.Where(u => u.IsActive == true);

if (txtFilterBy_UserName.Value.Length > 0))
{
    users = users.Where(u => u.UserName.ToLower().Contains(txtFilterBy_UserName.Value.ToLower()));
}

users = users.ToList();
```